# Docusign error trying to get envelope status

Tags: docusignapi

Starting on Sept 25 at 3:15 AM, after 4 years of trouble free operation, we are getting the following error whenever we make a SOAP call to requestStatusdEx:

"This user is not the sender or a recipient of the envelope.  Only the sender or a recipient of the envelope may perform the requested operation."

WebMethod action = http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0/RequestStatusEx

Any ideas where to start looking for the problem?

Thanks
Jim

Answer (score 1):

If it has been working for 4 years without code change, I'd contact DocuSign Customer Support for quickest resolution. Otherwise we'll need more information from you here (such as code sample of your call on creating the envelope and requesting status)